# How to install Image Capture by itself?

Tags: macos, image-capture

I was googling how to mass delete photos from my iPhone and the consensus was to use Image Capture. However, I couldn't find that application on my Mac. Is there a way I can install it individually?

If that's impossible, is there any other alternative app that does the same thing?

I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

Comment: Is it not in /Applications/Utilities? It should come pre-installed with your OS.

Comment: Not there already checked

Answer (score 1):

The application resides in `/Applications`, the corresponding (app) bundle is called `Image Capture.app`, but the Finder adapts the name to your language settings (it's listed as "Digitale Bilder.app" on a (Swiss) German setting).

One easy way to start it is to use Spotlight and search for "Image Capture". Should be one of the hits (usually the first), just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start it then.